# Why I cant make a class string as domainFn for pie chart in charts_flutter

Tags: charts, flutter

Hi there I am trying to make Piechart base on its [example](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/pie_charts/outside_label) 
But I change Just one thing, I changed

```
final int year
```

to

```
final String year
```

but for `domainFn` Im getting this error:

> ```
> {
>   "resource": "/home/saeb/AndroidStudioProjects/charts/lib/main.dart",
>   "owner": "dart",
>   "code": "return_of_invalid_type_from_closure",
>   "severity": 8,
>   "message": "The return type 'String' isn't a 'int', as defined by anonymous closure.",
>   "source": "dart",
>   "startLineNumber": 36,
>   "startColumn": 45,
>   "endLineNumber": 36,
>   "endColumn": 55,
>   "tags": []
> }
> ```

my label should be string not int, how I can do that?

my code:

```
    import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PieOutsideLabelChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<charts.Series> seriesList;
  final bool animate;

  PieOutsideLabelChart(this.seriesList, {this.animate});

  factory PieOutsideLabelChart.withSampleData() {
    return new PieOutsideLabelChart(
      _createSampleData(),
      animate: false,
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new charts.PieChart(seriesList,
        animate: animate,
        defaultRenderer: new charts.ArcRendererConfig(arcRendererDecorators: [
          new charts.ArcLabelDecorator(
              labelPosition: charts.ArcLabelPosition.outside)
        ]));
  }

  static List<charts.Series<LinearSales, int>> _createSampleData() {
    final data = [
      new LinearSales('a long text', 100),
      new LinearSales('even longer text', 75),
      new LinearSales('i am long text', 25),
      new LinearSales('the longest text ever', 5),
    ];
    return [
      new charts.Series<LinearSales, int>(
        id: 'Sales',
        domainFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.year,
        measureFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: data,
        labelAccessorFn: (LinearSales row, _) => '${row.year}: ${row.sales}',
      )
    ];
  }
}
class LinearSales {
  final String year;
  final int sales;

  LinearSales(this.year, this.sales);
}
main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'charts',
    home: new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("نمودار فلان"),),
      body:new ListView(children: <Widget>[
          new Card
          (child: PieOutsideLabelChart(PieOutsideLabelChart._createSampleData()),)
        //   ]
        //  ),
      ]
    )
  )
   )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very simple:

set year variable to int again:

```
final int year
```

and here use `toString()` method:

`labelAccessorFn: (LinearSales row, _) => '${row.year.toString()}: ${row.sales}',`

Comment: No. I want use string. Without integer in it

Comment: I don't get it why would you want to use String? but anyway .toString() will convert the int to a string

Comment: I want pie chart to show how much of my projects are complete how much are in progress and how much didnt start yet

Comment: @SaebMolaee no mater if its a string or int it will still be rendered as string the label is a string at the end, label can't be an integer

Answer (score 4):

It was syntax problem. my bad :D

I should change my charts.Series to `charts.Series<LinearSales, **String**>>` from `charts.Series<LinearSales, **int**>>`

this code works:

```
        import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PieOutsideLabelChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<charts.Series> seriesList;
  final bool animate;

  PieOutsideLabelChart(this.seriesList, {this.animate});

  factory PieOutsideLabelChart.withSampleData() {
    return new PieOutsideLabelChart(
      _createSampleData(),
      animate: false,
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new charts.PieChart(seriesList,
        animate: animate,
        defaultRenderer: new charts.ArcRendererConfig(arcRendererDecorators: [
          new charts.ArcLabelDecorator(
              labelPosition: charts.ArcLabelPosition.outside)
        ]));
  }

  static List<charts.Series<LinearSales, String>> _createSampleData() {
    final data = [
      new LinearSales('a long text', 100),
      new LinearSales('even longer text', 75),
      new LinearSales('i am long text', 25),
      new LinearSales('the longest text ever', 5),
    ];
    return [
      new charts.Series<LinearSales, String>(
        id: 'Sales',
        domainFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.year,
        measureFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: data,
        labelAccessorFn: (LinearSales row, _) => '${row.year}',
      )
    ];
  }
}
class LinearSales {
  final String year;
  final int sales;

  LinearSales(this.year, this.sales);
}
main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'charts',
    home: new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("نمودار فلان"),),
      body: PieOutsideLabelChart(PieOutsideLabelChart._createSampleData()),)

  )
   );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make a class string as domainFn for pie chart in charts_flutter.
it will take some adjustments
**Step 1: Add this to your chart so it gonna show label on outside of pie chart**

```
defaultRenderer: new charts.ArcRendererConfig(
         arcWidth: 60,
         arcRendererDecorators: [new charts.ArcLabelDecorator(
              labelPosition: charts.ArcLabelPosition.outside)]
      ),
```

**Step 2 : Now for customization of those label with string there on property.
which is labelAccessorFn**

```
String datas(int id,int value){
      if(id==0){
        return value.toString()+":RT";
      }else if(id==1){
        return value.toString()+":OT";
      }
      else if(id==2){
        return value.toString()+":IT";
      }
    return [
          new charts.Series<VfmProductivityPie, int>(
            id: 'Sales',
            domainFn: (VfmProductivityPie sales, _) => sales.id,
            measureFn: (VfmProductivityPie sales, _) => sales.value,
            data: data,
            labelAccessorFn: (VfmProductivityPie row, _) =>
             // print('object'),
             //'${row.id}r: ${row.value}',
             datas(row.id,row.value)
          )
        ];
```

**Note: write data function under _createSampleData**[working screenshot of piechart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpDxp.jpg)